# Machine learning, emphasize certain observations?

Tags: machine-learning

I have a multi-class machine learning problem for which I will try different methods on such as logistic regression, decision trees, multilayer perceptron etc.

The observations in the data set have an attribute which is an index from 1-5  which defines how important it is that a certain observation gets correctly classified (index 1 very important, 5 not important at all). My questions are:

Question 1: How should I emphasize to the models that the lower index observations have greater importance? I am thinking of duplicating these observations so the models fit the lower index observations more well, what other approaches are possible?

Question 2: What performance evaluation criterias can I use to find the models that predict these low index observations well? (appart from calculating the distribution of indexes among the correctly predicted instances.)

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer 1: Presenting the important patterns of the training set more often is the standard approach for this. If your training algorithm has something like a leraning rate (for example if you use backpropagation), you could also increase this parameter for the high priority patterns.

Answer 2: I would use a weighted mean square error and give the errors of the high priority patterns a larger weight.

Comment: Regarding the answer for the second question, I don't see how mean squared error is suppose to be used for a classification problem?

Comment: @Josi: I was assuming that (1) you do supervised classification ans (2) that the cells have continuous output values. If this is not the case, an different error measure might make more sense.

Comment: The first assumption is true but not the second. The output is discrete so the output is just a class label where only one label is correct and all other are incorrect. I've been looking at a few methods like F score and Hamming loss but I am having a hard time to decide.

What I am looking for is a  performance evaluation criteria that is:
- Somewhat complementary to classifiction accuracy
- Fairly simple
- Some kind of motivation on why I should use this method